# jQuery interactive chart needed - sliders

Tags: jquery, charts, slider

I was hoping someone came across a jQuery based charting plugin that allows some interaction with the chart. I need one that is essentially a line graph where each point can be slided up and down on y axis - to adjust the values.

I really like what .vizualize is doing where you still have a regular table display where javascript is not enabled. So if the chart would work on a similar basis it would be perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/), or the charting plugin [GraphaelJS](http://g.raphaeljs.com/)

In fact [this example](http://raphaeljs.com/ichart.html)  is very similar to what you describe.

Comment: I can confirm I was able to do what was needed with Graphael library. The examples the site provides are not very well structured code wise but are workable.

Comment: You just saved my life.
And this is the link working now http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/ichart.html

Comment: @Moiz, this little nugget from the past was quite good back then, however I imagine there are better alternatives out there now.  Try [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Check out jqPlot, http://www.jqplot.com/

Comment: Already had a look at it but couldn't find any examples that would do what is needed.

Comment: This is using jqplot. Not really sure if it is the best way, but it is doable: http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/customHighlighterCursorTrendline.html

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Fusion Charts](http://www.fusioncharts.com)

Comment: Very pretty indeed but again can't find any examples that support sliding inside the chart.